# can anyone explain the differences between the two allocs and why bad and good?

Tags: c, memory

can anyone explain the differences between the two allocs and why bad and good? what happen in each case of bad and good?

***bad alloc***

```
  void get_memory(char *arr, int length){
        if((arr=(char*)malloc(length * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        {
            puts("Not enough memory. Sorry.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    void main(void){
        char *str = NULL;
        get_memory(str, 128);
        strcpy(str,"Program illegally runs over memory !\n");
        puts(str);
        free(str);
    }
```

***good alloc***

```
void get_memory(char **arr, int length){
    if( (*arr = (char*)malloc(length * sizeof(char))) ==
        NULL)
    {
        puts("Not enough memory. Sorry.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
void main(void){
    char *str = NULL;
    get_memory(&str, 128);
    strcpy(str, "This program works fine !\n");
    puts(str);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: Why tagged C and C++? C - malloc C++ new

Comment: the first one assigns the pointer to a local, so the caller wont see it

Comment: First one is a memory leak. Str will still be NULL for the strcpy

Comment: BTW - Where is the ugly one?

Answer (score 3):

The bad is that in the first case the *pointer* `arr` is passed by value, it's value is modified in the function, and when returning the value is "forgotten". In the second code the *reference* to the pointer is passed, so the assigned value is retained when out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the "bad" example you are actually throwing away malloc's result, since "str" parameter is passe dby value and will mantain its NULL value after the call. In the second case the function receives a POINTER TO "str", so it's able to manipulate "str" and leave the correct value in it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered your question, I add an alternative:

```
void get_memory(char **arr, size_t length){
   if((*arr = malloc(length)) == NULL && 0 != length)
   {
       puts("Not enough memory. Sorry.\n");
       exit(-1);
   }
}
```

Reasoning: `length` shall not be negative. And when it is `0`, the result of `malloc` can be `NULL`.

`malloc` returns `void*`, which is automatically casted to an appropriate pointer type in C.

As per later C standard, `sizeof(char)` is 1.